# Bolding font using print when expression and inline style

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport

I currently have a `PrintWhenExpression` that is trying to use a if/else statement like this:

`$F{group_description} == "Total Accounts Opened:" ? $F{group_description}.text.setStyle(boldStyle) : $F{group_description}`

The only problem is that it isn't working. I want to bold $F{group_description} when it equals "Total Accounts Opened:" and have it not bold if else.

What is the proper inline style to bold a font?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I usually set a conditional style for things like this. In iReport's Report Inspector, you'll have to create a basic style (but you don't need to apply any elements to it) and then right click on that style and choose "Add conditional style". In that style's condition expression you can put $F{group_description} == "Total Accounts Opened:", and then check the box to make it bold.